# j-query showing syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a slider its not auto-play when i use this j-query code its showing syntax error. But i did'nt find syntax error. Please help

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var photoslider = new WallopSlider('.photo-slider');
    //autoplay
    var count = photoslider.allItemsArrayLength;
    var start = photoslider.currentItemIndex;
    var end = count + 1;
    var index = start;

    jQuery(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            photoslider.goTo(index);
            ++index;
            if (index == end) {
                index = start
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: From a quick indenting look I can first tell you that you don't have `});` at the end

Comment: Delete your question before more downvoting...)

Answer (score 2):

Please put `});` after your coding

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put the closing curly braces and parenthesis of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`. Which is `})`

Answer (score 1):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     var photoslider = new WallopSlider('.photo-slider');
     //autoplay
     var count = photoslider.allItemsArrayLength;
     var start = photoslider.currentItemIndex;
     var end = count + 1;
     var index = start;

    jQuery(function () {  
         setInterval(function () {
             photoslider.goTo(index);
             ++index;
             if (index == end) {
                 index = start
            }
         }, 3000);
     });
 }); //--> this is missing
```